# How to pass a view or a custom parameter to GestureDetector?

Tags: android, kotlin, gesturedetector

This is probably a noob question but I'm still new to Kotlin. I'm creating a single gesture detector for a few views and would like to pass the view to the listener, or even better a custom parameter.

My code:

```
val gestureDetector = GestureDetector(this@EditProfileActivity, object : GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
    override fun onSingleTapConfirmed(e: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        Log.d("myApp", "single tap confirmed  press")
    }
})
profilePic1.setOnTouchListener { view, event -> gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event) }
profilePic2.setOnTouchListener { view, event -> gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event) }
```

I'm attaching the same listener to different views and want a way to differenatiate between the views in the override functions. How can I get the view in those functions, and in addition is it possible to pass a custom parameter such as Int

Also, I tried to create my custom gestureDetector, but I get an error that "none of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied", since I add the custom position argument, although I'm making a custom detector so I don't understand why it's not working:

```
class detector (context: Context?, listener: GestureDetector, handler: Handler, unused: Boolean, val position: Int )
    : GestureDetector(this@EditProfileActivity, GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener(), null, false, position ) {
```

Comment: Create your own class that extends GestureDetector, and in the class constructor, provide it with a view or use a builder pattern.

Comment: Thanks Ahmad I tried to implement a custom class that extends GestureDetector but it's still not working, could you please take a look? I edited my question to include the code

Comment: What's not working? Post logs.

Comment: I'm getting the error "none of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied" because I add in the position:Int, and it's an argument that shouldn't be included in the GestureDetecor, but I don't udnerstand why it's not working since I'm extending it with a custom class

Comment: Post the class and how you are instantiating in your question. Don't update it in the answer below.

Comment: Please take a look at my question, I posted the code of the class I'm trying to instaniate, although the answer I posted is a working solution so it's ok already thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I did find a solution, maybe it can benefit others. I'm not sure if it's ideal to create more than one gesture detectors, although they all direct to the same class:

```
    val gesture1 = GestureDetector(this@EditProfileActivity, GestureListener(1))
    profilePic1.setOnTouchListener { view, event -> gesture1.onTouchEvent(event) }

    val gesture2 = GestureDetector(this@EditProfileActivity, GestureListener(2))
    profilePic2.setOnTouchListener { view, event -> gesture2.onTouchEvent(event) }

class GestureListener (val position: Int) : GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
    override fun onDoubleTap(e: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        Log.d("HAVERI", position.toString())
        return super.onDoubleTap(e)
    }
}
```